# $A=\bigl\{z:\arg\left(\frac{z-1}{z}\right)=\frac{π}{2}\bigr\}$ and $B=\{z:\arg\left(z-1\right)=π\}$. Find $(A\;\cap\;B)$.

Tags: complex-numbers

A & B are sets of complex numbers

Since $\arg(z-1)=π$, therefore $z$ is a purely real complex number. Thus, $\arg\left(\frac{z-1}{z}\right)$ has to be equal to $0$ or $π$.

So, $A \cap B=\varnothing$.

Is my approach correct?

Comment: Or $\arg{(z-1)/z}=π$ if $0<z<1$

Comment: Yes, that too. I was only aiming to prove that $arg\left(\frac{z-1}{z}\right)\neq\frac{π}{2}$.

Comment: So you may restate your conclusion in your answer,  in order to be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A={z:$arg(\frac{z-1}{z})=\frac{π}{2}$}
$$ $$
Locus of z is semicircle above x axis with (0,0) and (1,0) as one of its diameter and z$\ne$0 , 1.
$$. $$
B = {z: arg(z-1)=π } 
$$. $$
Locus of z is a ray from z=1 towards -ve direction of x axis where z$\ne$1.
$$. $$
Hence no z satisfy both locus
$$ $$
For more on complex number you can refer to https://www.mathsdiscussion.com/best-iitjee-maths-for-mains-and-advance/